# A design update is coming!

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some updates to the design lately, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be a tease, now... *when* are the new profiles & other goodies coming?

Comment: @Iszi As soon as possible :)

Comment: An update that unlocks another update? You remind me of Windows Update.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin How much is that in days?

Comment: @LucasKauffman We have a lot on our plates so I'd say by the end of the month

Comment: @StéphaneMartin that's a good deadline, I like it.

Comment: @TildalWave By the end of August 2015 (see, I said 2015 :) )

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Woah woah, lets not get carried away with specifics

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Wait a sec... In which era, and by which standard calendar?

Comment: @Iszi, [Republican Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar)

Comment: *it will give you access to the new profile* sadness. :(

Comment: *unsure what the point of the local announcement was, weeks in advance of anything happening, when a global announcement occurred months ago*

Comment: My cheese ... looks different.

Comment: @kalina We did an announcement on this site so people don't find that one day things changed on the site and they were not prepared. We really do care about our users and we are always transparent about what we're doing on our sites, it's also the perfect moment to ask if anything goes wrong / needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Type: [bug](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)

Priority: [normal](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal)

The hmenus div is wider than the content div.

[image]

Comment: I think that might be on purpose.

Comment: @raz - the problem is it looks different on the main and meta sites. The outer rectangle doesn't blend in nicely, and this creates a visually jarring effect.

Answer (score 0):

Type: [feature-request](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Priority: [low](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low)

Main site "Add Comment" button color is a bit on the brick red side (R:198, G:57, B:41). While color tastes differ, please consider making the color purer.

[image]